# Significance blessing for Moses like Aaron

Tags: numbers, moses

I've found no significance reward for Moses dedicated service, neither for his descendants unlike Aaron that got almost, if not all the blessings in `Numbers 18:8-20`. My question is, are there any significance reward given to him and his descendants?

Comment: Interesting question. This would involve what Moses _represents_ in scripture : what his office was and whether - or not - that office would continue in perpetuity ( as opposed to the priesthood).

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Moses and Aaron were both Levites from the Kohathites (Ex 6:16,18, 20). So any of Moses' children would have also been Kohathites and had similar privileges but just not the priesthood.
Moses also had the singular privilege of witnessing God's glory (Ex 33:18-23). He also was the mediator of the Law covenant (Ex 24:3-8). He oversaw the building of the tabernacle of which the pattern was given to Moses by God himself (Ex chaps 25-29; Le chaps 8,9). And most significantly, Moses spoke to God "face to face" (Nu 12:6-8).

Comment: I think it is clear from scripture what you state in your second paragraph. But the question was about the reward to Moses and to his descendants, which you have not addressed.

Comment: You did a good job in corroborating the widely available blessing for all Levites, which doesn't give a distinction for Moses special blessing for service. I'll like to know if there's any. To this I'll say he's just a lump in the crowd of Levites who collects tithes from the Israelites. The whole best of things went to Aaron and his descendants, and nothing was ever mentioned of Moses or his descendants getting special benefit.